# 2 circle with different radii covers same path on same number of turns... crack the fallacy

Tags: geometry

> I found this puzzle from an old issue of a science magazine [*জ্ঞান ও বিজ্ঞান*](http://bangiyabijnanparishad.in/journal.php) ("Knowledge and Science")(August, 1977); submitted by Amal Dash, a teacher of Scottish Church school, Kolkata; as mentioned in the magazine.
>
> Incidentally; the answer wasn't published there.
>
> The original publication did not contained any sketch. I've added a few to make it easily readable.

---

A wheel has an outer radius r<sub>1</sub> and an inner radius r<sub>2</sub>. The wheel is rolling on a floor.

Normally, r<sub>1</sub> > r<sub>2</sub>.

Before the wheel was being rolled, the topmost (from ground) point of  outer  margin (dot A) and inner margin (dot B) was marked with color dots.

After rolling; the wheel was stopped in a situation, when the 2 colored dots came upwards. So, in the mean-path; the wheel turned complete (integer) turns.

---

Since the both circles on the wheel revolved n-complete turns;  then point A (on big circle) should have been shifted 2nπr<sub>1</sub> and similarly the point B (on small circle) should have been shifted  2nπr<sub>2</sub>.

But if so; since we can see after complete turns the point A and B came to similar orientation as initial, and so dots A and B shows *same shift* from their own initial positions in horizontal direction; so 2nπr<sub>1</sub> should be =  2nπr<sub>2</sub>; 
ie. r<sub>1</sub> = r<sub>2</sub> . And we know very well that r<sub>1</sub> ≠ r<sub>2</sub>.

So, where lies the fallacy? what was going inside the circle?

[image: Figures]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may be a better question for the Math SE.
Having said that ....

> The fallacy is that the inner circle is not tracing out its own perimeter - it's along for the ride.  You can see how quickly this breaks down if you consider the limit as $r_{\small_2}\to0$ that if both circles were independently moving $2n\pi r$ for their respective radii, as suggested in the fallacious argument, that this would leave the center-point of the wheel essentially motionless while the outer rim of the wheel moved as expected—a clearly nonsensical situation.
>
>  Since the inner surface of the wheel is not independent of the outer surface of the wheel, they both rotate together, but only point A on the outer circle is tracing out the perimeter of its $2n\pi r_{\small_1}$ circumference.

Comment: IMO it suits better with puzzling because its main focus is a fallacy. As well overlap of physics, mathematics etc. wit puzzling is pretty common; including Carroll's classic '[Monkey on a Rope](https://www.futilitycloset.com/2006/11/22/a-weighty-problem/)' problem; which are frequently discussed puzzle related literature.

Answer (score 3):

No different answer than User@Rubio; but a little bit graphical addition.

> For me; the fallacy was a subconscious illusion that, ***as-if*** the wheel's movement does not depend upon which portion of it is touching the ground or track. Such as;  ***as-if*** the wheel should have same movement whether it run as in OP or as in Fig.4 of following diagram. ***But that is NOT***.  <sub>And the best way to clear up this illusion is; to visualize and compare the [Cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid)s generated by the different spots on the wheel.    In the following diagram (fig. 1 to 5);   I did a try with simplest mensuration formulae and MS-Paint, considering  r1= 40 pixels  and r2= 20 pixels (as shown by horizontal and vertical ruler of ms-Paint on maximum zoom). In fig 2 and 3; I took 8 successive configurations (each differ 90 ° rotational phase). (In fig. 5 actually more samples were required, but not shown to keep the diagram readable.) . In each situation; at first the path moved by the wheel per 90 ° rotation has been calculated, and on that interval the wheel is repeatedly pasted.</sub>  [image: The Cycloids]  The point B in **Fig. 2** (Like OP)   and **fig. 3** (where a wheel of r2 radius, is running); are generating 2 different cycloid path. In Fig-1 the cycloid generated by B is horizontal-direction much more stretched, that is eating up that extra length. **Fig. 6** Shows another condition, if the whole wheel (with point A and B); could be run on the inner circle (as in **Fig. 5**) we would get the same cycloid as Fig3 for inner circle; but for point A, a more special cycloid found, which is loopy and compressed (along horizontal direction) than that of **fig.2**. In **Fig. 5** The colour variation (red to yellow) in larger circle is to cleanly trace the looping-back.

P.S. The use of ms-paint curve-tool done much on eye-gaze. so certainly there exists error. However all sorts of suggestions and criticism are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is better understood if you first consider what is happening to the centre (I'm British, hence the original spelling) of the circle. Applying the $2 \pi r$ approach clearly doesn't work here as the circumference of a circle with no radius is zero. However, the axle of a wheel on a vehicle moves without describing any curved path.

Similarly, the point on the smaller circle is moving - partly owing to its placement on a rotating body and partly owing to the movement of the whole wheel - the contribution of which is seen by the axle's movement.

Comment: Also thanks for the Grammar and Etymology related informations.